# Multithread HttpWebRequest hangs randomly on responseStream

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest, fiddler, freeze

I'm coding a multithreaded web-crawler that performs a lot of concurrent httpwebrequests every second using hundreds of threads, the application works great but sometimes(randomly) one of the webrequests hangs on the getResponseStream() completely ignoring the timeout(this happen when I perform hundreds of requests concurrently) making the crawling process never end, the strange thing is that with fiddler this never happen and the application never hang, it is really hard to debug because it happens randomly.

I've tried to set

Keep-Alive = false

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

but I still get the strange behavior, any ideas?

Thanks

HttpWebRequest code:

```
  public static string RequestHttp(string url, string referer, ref CookieContainer cookieContainer_0, IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.UserAgent = randomuseragent();
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer_0;
        request.Proxy = proxy;
        request.Timeout = 15000;
        request.Referer = referer;
        //request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 15000;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[0x400];
                int count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (count != 0)
                {
                    list.AddRange(buffer.ToList<byte>().GetRange(0, count));
                    if (list.Count >= 0x100000)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    try
                    {
           HERE IT HANGS SOMETIMES --->             count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        continue;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                //responseStream.Close();
                int num2 = 0x200 * 0x400;
                if (list.Count >= num2)
                {
                    list.RemoveRange((num2 * 3) / 10, list.Count - num2);
                }
                byte[] bytes = list.ToArray();
                str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
                Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;
                if (str.ToLower().IndexOf("charset=") > 0)
                {
                    encoding = GetEncoding(str);
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
                str = encoding.GetString(bytes);
               // response.Close();
            }
        }
        return str.Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property "Gets or sets the time-out value in milliseconds for the GetResponse and GetRequestStream methods." The default value is 100,000 milliseonds (100 seconds).

The [ReadWriteTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property, "Gets or sets a time-out in milliseconds when writing to or reading from a stream." The default is 300,000 milliseconds (5 minutes).

You're setting `Timeout`, but leaving `ReadWriteTimeout` at the default, so your reads can take up to five minutes before timing out. You probably want to set `ReadWriteTimeout` to a lower value. You might also consider limiting the size of data that you download. With my crawler, I'd sometimes stumble upon an unending stream that would eventually result in an out of memory exception.

Something else I noticed when crawling is that sometimes closing the response stream will hang. I found that I had to call `request.Abort` to reliably terminate a request if I wanted to quit before reading the entire stream.

Comment: Yes, I already tried the ReadWriteTimeout, I just deleted it because I'm doing tests with Fiddler, if Fiddler is opened the problem never occur and no request hangs(without using the ReadWriteTimeout), I'm just investigating with fiddler right now and why if I keep it opened it "fix" my application.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing apparent in the code you provided.

Why did you comment response.Close() out?

Documentation hints that connections may run out if not explicitly closed. The response getting disposed may close the connection but just releasing all the resources is not optimal I think. Closing the response will also close the stream so that is covered.

The system hanging without timeout can be just a network issue making the response object a dead duck or the problem is due the high number of threads resulting in memory fragmentation.

Looking at anything that may produce a pattern may help find the source:

1. How many threads are typically running (can you bundle request sets in less threads)
2. How is the network performance at the time the thread stopped
3. Is there a specific count or range when it happens
4. What data was processed last when it happened (are there any specific control characters or sequences of data that can upset the stream)

Want to ask more questions but not enough reputation so can only reply.

Good luck!

Comment: Currently 1 thread = 1 request, I think it does not depend on the netowrk performance because it happens on both win7 and on my server running win 2008, it happens totally randomly on random urls, but all this is fixed if I keep fiddler opened, it never hangs, that's the strange thing, I'm not really an expert on debugging with fiddler and this is the first time I code a multithreaded application.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code that does something similar, it's also used to access multiple web sites, each call is in a different task. The difference is that I only read the stream once and then parse the results. That might be a way to get around the stream reader locking up randomly or at least make it easier to debug.

```
       try
       {
           _webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse();
           if(_request.HaveResponse)
           {
               if (_webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
               {
                   var _stream = _webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                   using (var _streamReader = new StreamReader(_stream))
                   {
                       string str = _streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```